# Why am I getting an error with a form for a nested resource in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have the following link_to:

new_vendor_review_path(@vendor)

This takes me to the uRL:

domain.com/vendors/vendor_id/reviews/new

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `reviews_path' for #<#<Class:0xb6f01ca0>:0xb6eff658>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% semantic_form_for [@vendor, @review] do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.inputs %>
3:   <%= f.buttons %>
4:
```

Controller for Review:

```
4   def new
 15     @vendor = Vendor.find_using_slug(params[:vendor_id])
 16     @review = @vendor.reviews.build
 17     @review.user_id = current_user.id if user_signed_in?
 18   end
 19 
 20   def create
 21     @vendor = Vendor.find(@review.vendor_id)
 22     @review = @vendor.reviews.build(params[:review])
 23     if @review.save
 24       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created review."
 25       redirect_to @review
 26     else
 27       render :action => 'new'
 28     end
 29   end
```

Review.rb (model):

```
1 class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   attr_accessible :title, :summary, :vendor_id, :user_id, :tag_list, :competitor_list
  3   is_sluggable :title
  4   acts_as_voteable
  5   acts_as_commentable
  6   
  7   validates :title, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 10, :maximum => 50}
  8   validates :user_id, :presence => true
  9     
 10   belongs_to :user
 11   belongs_to :vendor
```

Here is from my routes.rb

```
2   devise_for :users
  3 
  4   match 'reviews/vote_up' => 'reviews#vote_up'
  5 
  6   resources :users
  7   resources :reviews
  8   
  9   resources :vendors do
 10     resources :reviews, :shallow => true
 11   end
```

Comment: it might be because the URL you are going says 404 Page not Found,hm?

Comment: do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews` inside your Vendor model?

Comment: This is the eror I get -- as seen above:  undefined method `reviews_path' for #<#<Class:0xb6d0f064>:0xb6d0dcf0> ... why is it looking for reviews_path?

Comment: do you have `has_many :reviews` as well?  I haven't seen this exact error with nested routes yet.

Comment: yes, I do...it's strange, it keeps asking me for the review_path which does not show up in rake routes...I made :shallow => true but still...

Comment: Can you post your model and controller code?

Comment: @Patrick -- I posted it -- it is working, but I'd still like someone to check it...what i did was added a resources :reviews but I don't think I should have had to do that.

Comment: If you make the changes suggested by @htanata, does all work?  If not, then I think if you upload your routes.rb file, the answer will be right in front of us.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a routing error to me. The error is saying that the method `reviews_path` doesn't exist. This method is usually generated by adding a [resourceful route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls) in `routes.rb`.

Try adding this on your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :reviews
```

Comment: yeah, that fixed it....but then I have resources :reviews twice, one as stated, and one as nested...is that right?

Comment: @Angela: I think it should be `reviews` nested within `vendors`.

Comment: yes, I have it...but now I also have it stand alone -- is the right?

Comment: @Angela: OK, I get it. You can remove the stand alone `resources :reviews`. Your problem is with the form. The form should be `semantic_form_for([:vendor, @review])`. `:vendor` should be a symbol, not the object. I will update my answer.

Comment: @htanata -- how come its a symbol....not an object....when do I use both objects because I've seen tutorials do that....

Comment: @Angela: Whoops, sorry. Yes, you're right. It should be an object if it's a nested resources. I was talking about namespaced routes. You may want to post your `routes.rb` so I can have a better idea of what's going on.